# infinite product of polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

Let $p_k$ be a complex polynomial with $p_k(0)=1$, with no zero in $\{|z| \le k^3\}$ and $deg(p_k) \le k$. Show that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i(z)$ converges.

One can observe that $p_k(z)=1+h_k(z)$ but I dont know how to determine the convergence of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty h_i(z)$.

Comment: Isn't there some further condition? Perhaps on the degree of $p_k$? As written, the product need not converge.

Comment: Should k and i be the same?

Comment: @DanielFischer yes ofcourse, so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the polynomial $p_k$ has zeros $\zeta_1,\dotsc, \zeta_{d_k}$, where $d_k = \deg p_k$, then you can write

$$p_k(z) = \prod_{j = 1}^{d_k}\biggl(1 - \frac{z}{\zeta_j}\biggr).$$

In that form, with the constraints on the zeros of $p_k$, it is easy to show that the product $\prod\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} p_i(z)$ converges locally uniformly on $\mathbb{C}$.